# Reversing default scale gradient ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, reverse, heatmap

I am newbie, I am trying to desing a heat map. This is my code:

```
ggplot(gd, aes(Qcountry, Q6_1_Q6d), order = TRUE) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = prob), colour = "white") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs( y = "Main reason for mobility", x = "Country") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "(%)")
```

Which produces a perfect chart, my problem is low levels are dark blue, and higher values are light blue, which is not intuitive. Most common way to do is use `rev()`. But in my case I dont know how to. So, is it possible to reverse this **default scale**?
[This is the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiy78.jpg)

Other question, is there a way to create a scale gradient only with one colour. I mean, `scale_fill_gradient/scale_fill_gradientn`  need to set a low color and high color `(low = "", high = "")` and I want to change the blue by red.

Thanks so much for your support.

Comment: For your second question (please only ask one question at a time), you'll need two different shades of red. Like `'red'` and `scales::muted('red')`. You might want to look at the `viridis` package for superior color scales.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`?scale_colour_gradient` shows the default values of `low = "#132B43"` and `high = "#56B1F7"`.

Simply switch those around:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7")
```

[image]

Personally, I think this is less intuitive than the default.

---

Alternatively, you can use a reverse scale, but this will also flip the legend to start at the top:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(trans = 'reverse')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for improving my code in a simple way. This works perfect!

Answer (score 9):

you can use the color palettes from `RColorBrewer`[(link)](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html) library and assign the direction of the color gradient

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z, width = w), colour = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette ="RdBu", direction = -1) # or direction=1


# data
  df <- data.frame( x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
                    y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
                    z = rep(1:5, each = 2),
                    w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your answer! Works perfect!