# Reverse colors from ggmap points

Tags: r, colors, ggmap

I want to reverse the color of the points and the label from the following ggmap creation:

```
ggmap(Map) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes (x = Longitude, 
                                y = Latitude, 
                                color = RPM)) +
  labs(y = "Latitude", x = "Longitude", color = "RPM")
```

I wouldn't like to change by now the data set to spatial points.

I'm getting the following result:

[image: Map]

I have tried the following addition to the code presented:

```
scale_colour_brewer(direction = -1)
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

*Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale*

Comment: You can set the upper and lower colors to whatever you want. Instead of `scale_color_brewer`, try `scale_color_gradient(high = "blue4", low = "lightblue")`

Comment: What are the default colors used on the case I presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer at: [Reversing default scale gradient ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515112/reversing-default-scale-gradient-ggplot2)

Simply switched place with the found R color default pallete for the case:

```
scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7")
```